# Why is the RSA fingerprint for my private key the same as my public key?

Tags: ssh

These two are identical. Why? I thought the RSA fingerprint is the output of a hash function, which means that two different inputs (the private and public key) should result in two different outputs.

```
user$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2048 SHA256:zZ2qBu6JGxlTWnLUUDU4UFl8uzLPCoi8ze1BPII/Uhc etc etc

user$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
2048 SHA256:zZ2qBu6JGxlTWnLUUDU4UFl8uzLPCoi8ze1BPII/Uhc etc etc
```

Answer (score 6):

A fingerprint is calculated as a hash, but it is not calculated by blindly hashing the input file – the protocol usually specifies exactly *which* parts of a key to hash and in what order. (And this might be different between protocols: an SSHv2 pubkey will have a different fingerprint than a PEM pubkey even if they contain absolutely identical RSA parameters.)

The usual rule everywhere is that the fingerprint is *always* based on hashing the public part only; it's more useful that way. Since the public key can always be derived from the private key file (which in reality holds all parameters, public and private) it means you will always calculate the correct type of fingerprint.

For example, if the first command showed a different kind of fingerprint (one that only you can calculate) it would be completely useless for sharing with e.g. a sysadmin who's installing your key on a server. The same applies to fingerprints in X.509 and PGP – their main purpose *is* to be a short string to be shared.

Comment: Relevant: [How does a keypair fingerprint work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173969/how-does-a-keypair-fingerprint-work)